# how to add multiple images with each of its constraints using For/While loop

Tags: ios, xcode6

What i want to achieve is set buttons/images Horizontally Centered with main view, including its width set to 75% of the screen width.
I want to fit like 7 such images/buttons vertically on the screen (line-by-line).

I am using the following code, which is working perfect:

```
UIImageView *l1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
[l1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"level-1"]];
[l1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
l1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:l1];

NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:l1
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:20.f
                                  ];
[self.view addConstraint:c1];
NSLayoutConstraint *c1b = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:l1
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:0.f
                          ];
[self.view addConstraint:c1b];
NSLayoutConstraint *c1c = [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:l1
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.view
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           multiplier:0.75f
                           constant:0.f
                           ];
[self.view addConstraint:c1c];
```

Instead of repeating the same code for different images, i want to use some iteration process and increment the image name **[UIImage imageNamed:@"level-xxx"]]** and bind top position to the bottom position of the last added item.

How it would be possible? Thx

Comment: Have you made an attempt yet? Can you show it? How does it fail?

Comment: @AaronBrager its not failing, the above code works well, its just i need to know if this is possible to achieve using some loop by incrementing.

Comment: I'm not talking about the above code. I'm asking if you've tried writing a version that uses iteration yet.

Comment: @AaronBrager no sorry, not yet.

Comment: I suggest you try it yourself before asking someone else to do it for you. You'll learn more that way.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 9 introduces a new class called UIStackView that allows you to do this :

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/31/2/uistackview-by-example

There are even back-ports of this to iOS 7 on Github.

Some people might downvote me for this but sometimes , when it comes to autolayout I just say , $@#& this I'll write the layout code myself. And this is one of those cases (especially when UIStackView is not available).

First create all your views and store them in an array in viewDidLoad.

Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` on your view controller and loop through the array , set the frames and lay them out one by one.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSArray* imageList = self.imageViewList

    // calculate it if necessary
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(200,200)
    CGFloat spacing = 50
    for(UIView *view in imageList) {
         view.center = startPoint
         startPoint = CGPointMake(startPoint.x , startPoint.y + spacing)
    }
}
```

This is way more obvious , way easier to debug than a mess of constraints created in code.